# #python 2.7 How to Run Length Decode (RLE to string)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wish to decode a section of RLE into non-encoded output e.g:

```
01,01a01d57801d01a01,
```

into

```
,ad888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888da,
```

I have attempted using this module:

```
def decode(lst):
    return ''.join(c * n for n,c in lst)
```

but this gives me a "too many values to unpack"
any help would be appreciated.
I have no clue how to solve this, even not fixing my module is fine, please, any help whatsoever is good.

Comment: for n, c in lst expects tuple / group /list  of two elements in lst data. if your lst is the string splitted by (",") above, then you'll get the said error, for it will try to unpack lst into three parts, not two as you expect

Answer (score 0):

**WOW**

```
    import re

def decode(lst):
    return ''.join(c * int(n) for n,c in lst)

def openingthefile():
    x=1
    myfile=open('LogoRLE.txt','r')
    details =myfile.readline()
    while details is not "":
        mylist=re.findall(r'(\d\d)?(.)', details)
        print decode(mylist)
        details=myfile.readline()

    myfile.close()
    return details
contents=openingthefile()

mylist=re.findall(r'(\d\d)?(.)', contents)
```

Comment: Do you care to explain what this code does and why it's a solution for your problem? A little bit of text might help others to understand the solution too :-)